# Same question by different users, different programming languages required

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

I'm a long time lurker user of SO and started just collaborating, so I'd like to better understand what should drive a user on marking a question as duplicated. I did some search around the meta but couldn't find a case that relates to this:

A user asks for a implementation of said algorithm on C. It is marked as answered, with two implementation on pseudo-code.

Another user then asks for the same algorithm, but tags the question as C# and states the implementation isn't constrained by performance. He also claimed to have searched and found other implementations that where not clear enough or didn't apply. He didn't say anything about the former question, though, so he could possibly have missed it. The question is then marked as duplicated.

As having a part on the case (by posting an answer), I was curious about the criteria a user should adopt, as it seemed one should assume the OP will be capable of adapting a code from another language.

Of course I'm assuming a case where duplicated answer does not serve the OP (which I don't know if this one was), but I think that it is plausible that a inexperienced programmers would have trouble translating from one programming language to another.

Also, the duplicated question info states this:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new
>   question.

... which doesn't make much sense in this case, as another question like this would just be equally framed as duplicated.

The following are the questions in case:

C: [Algorithm to pick values from array that sum closest to a target value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134275/algorithm-to-pick-values-from-array-that-sum-closest-to-a-target-value)

C#: [Find elements which sum is closest to a given value [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269768/find-elements-which-sum-is-closest-to-a-given-value/30270088#30270088)

Hope that you guys could guide me on this one. Being having a really good time contributing and just wish to do the right thing when I find a similar situation.

Comment: OK. Doing a little comment-cleaning now.

Comment: I don't have time to find references, but the guidance I've always read and followed is that if the constraints for the solution are different, then it's a different question. The C# constraint is enough to justify a different question than one constrained to C; if performance were the only difference, I'd expect some clarification about why the more performant solution wasn't acceptable. Not sure what people were thinking closing as a dupe. That said, the question probably shouldn't be reopened until we get some clarification; several users comment that it's unclear what result the OP wants.